# How can I change color of MUI TimelineConnector?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I want to change color of all timeline. I tred to set inside JSX this "color="primary" but it works only with 
What I'm doing wrong?

```
<Timeline>
 <TimelineItem>
  <TimelineSeparator>
   <TimelineDot color="primary/>
    <TimelineConnector />
  </TimelineSeparator>
  <TimelineContent>Eat</TimelineContent>
 </TimelineItem>
</Timeline>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<TimelineDot style={{ color: 'red' }}/>
```

or you can also use `sx` property of `MUI`

```
 <TimelineDot sx={{ color: 'red' }}/>
```

Comment: doesn't work with <TimelineConnector />

Comment: try sx property of MUI